# Turning a text file with words and their positions into a sentence

Tags: python

Say I had a text file with some comments, and then keys and values like so:

```
# The following is
# a list of words and their positions
I: 1
like: 2
to: 3, 5
go: 4
cafes: 6
```

How would I go about turning this into a sentence ('I like to go to cafes')? I supposed I should try to turn the text into a dictionary first, but was already having trouble removing comments and splitting it into keys and values...
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file, appending the word and positions as tuples to a list. Then sort that list, remove the indices and join the words:

```
with open(inputfilename) as inputfile:
    words = []
    for line in inputfile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        word, positions = line.split(':')
        words.extend((int(p), word) for p in positions.split(','))

print ' '.join([w for p, w in sorted(words)])
```

Demo:

```
>>> with open(inputfilename) as inputfile:
...     words = []
...     for line in inputfile:
...         line = line.strip()
...         if not line or line.startswith('#'):
...             continue
...         word, positions = line.split(':')
...         words.extend((int(p), word) for p in positions.split(','))
... 
>>> print ' '.join([w for p, w in sorted(words)])
I like to go to cafes
```

Comment: That worked great thanks! If you don't mind, could you explain
the last two lines?

Comment: One is a generator expression; it's a loop in a single expression that produces items based on that loop. Here it produces `(int(p), word)` tuples for each `p` in the `positions.split(',')` sequence.

Comment: In other words, we split `positions` on a comma, turn each split string into an integer and create a tuple of that integer together with the corresponding word.

Comment: `words.extend()` takes that whole sequence and adds them to the `words` list, one by one.

Comment: The `' '.join()` call takes the input list, which should be strings, and stitches them together with the `' '` part, a space. It use a list comprehension to pick out each word from the `(position, word)` tuples, which we sorted first.

Comment: Sorting a series of tuples sorts first by the first value, then on the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 read the content into a dict

step 2 the sorted for sort the content in dict.

shep3 then finally fetch the value using foreach and then concatenate by + to produce sentence .