# return a dictionary with dictinct words as keys and it's position of occurence in the text as value

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, dictionary, return

Say I have a string

```
"I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
```

I am trying to write a function which will return a dictionary that will look like the following:

```
{'i":[0,1,2],'say':[0,1],'what':[0,1],'mean':[0,1],'do':[2]}
```

What it's doing is that it's taking each character, only once, into dictionary as a key and displaying what sentence it appears in as the value relating that key. So for eg, the word "mean" appears in the first [0] and second [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926383/counting-vowels) sentences. On the other hand, the word "do" only appears in the third sentence, hence the:

```
'do':[2]
```

in the output.

This is the code I have come up with after changing everything I can think of around to get a list for values to pair with each keys.

```
def wordsD(text):
#split each sentences at '.'
myList = text.lower().split('.')
#declare empty dictionary for the counter
myDict = {}
counterList = []
for sentence in myList:
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        index = words.index(word)
        counterList.append(index)
        if word not in myDict:
            myDict[word] = list()
            myDict[word].append(index)
        else:
            myDict[word]= list()
            myDict[word].append(index)


return myDict


text=('I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do.')
print(wordsD(text))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
{'mean': [1], 'what': [2], 'say': [4], 'i': [0], 'do': [1]}
```

But now I am not sure if I understood the question wrong or I am missing something in my code. Any help would be great!! Even a pointer in the right direction would help me out since I am coming up blank even when I try to write a psudo code for this problem. Thank you!

I looked at [Counting vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926383/counting-vowels) and [Turning a text file with words and their positions into a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274439/turning-a-text-file-with-words-and-their-positions-into-a-sentence) but I still cant figure out how to make the list as values for each keys.

Comment: It just means that the word 'do' was seen in sentence at an index of [2], which is the third sentence in my input.

Comment: i donno wt are you trying to achieve from comment. Try reading the part directly above `'do':[2]` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, you were making a new list in both the `if` and the `else` statements instead of appending to the existing list.

Changing

```
else:
    myDict[word] = list()
    myDict[word].append(index)
```

to

```
else:
    myDict[word].append(index)
```

solves that issue.

Secondly, your code is tracking the index within a given sentence (ie the word position) and not the sentences it is present in (which your question indicates you want).  The following code should fix that issue

```
def wordsD(text):
    myList = text.lower().split('.')
    myDict = {}

    for i in range(len(myList)):
        words = myList[i].split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in myDict:
                myDict[word] = [i]
            else:
                if i not in myDict[word]:
                    myDict[word].append(i)

    return myDict
```

Comment: i changed the else statement to only myDict[word].append(index), and I am getting 
    {'mean': [4, 1], 'i': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'say': [1, 4], 'do': [1], 'what': [2, 2]}

I am trying to get the following output:
    {'o': 1, 'e': 2, 'i': 0, 'a': 1, 'u': 5}

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason, I couldn't think of doing len(myList) and as you pointed out, my logic was wrong too. Instead of trying to look for the position of the sentence in which the word was in, I was looking for the position of the word. Thank you!

Comment: If you prefer the readability of using `sentence` then just add a counter variable outside of the loop and then increment it in the loop

Comment: Or use enumerate, which completely slipped my mind until I looked at these other answers

Comment: it does look like enumerate is more efficient, but I am a beginner in Python, I would like to get the basics down correct first, but I will definitely look into enumerate.

Answer (score 3):

This will definitely help you.

```
string = "I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."

DICT = {}

LIST  =  string.split('.')

WORDS = list(set(string.lower().replace('.',"").split()))

LIST = [set((x.lower()).split()) for x in LIST]

for i in range(len(LIST)):
    for item in WORDS:
        if item in LIST[i]:
            DICT.setdefault(item, []).append(i)
print(DICT)
```

OUTPUT

```
{'i': [0, 1, 2], 'do': [2], 'say': [0, 1], 'what': [0, 1], 'mean': [0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`index` now represents the position of the word in the sentence, not the index of the sentence. Try this:

```
for index, sentence in enumerate(myList):
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def wordsD(text):
#split each sentences at '.'
    myList = text.lower().split('.')
    #declare empty dictionary for the counter
    myDict = {}
    counterList = []

# use the enumerate here
    for senten_no,sentence in enumerate(myList): 
        words = sentence.split()
        for word in words:
            index = words.index(word)
            counterList.append(index)
            if word not in myDict:
                myDict[word] = list()
                myDict[word].append(senten_no)
            else:
                if not senten_no in myDict[word]:
                    myDict[word].append(senten_no)


    return myDict


    text=('I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do.')
print(wordsD(text))
```

For every time Your appending index of the word rather than index of Sentence. Use Enumerate for the sentence . which keep index so while appending append it with sentence Index

Comment: When I use it like that, I get closer to my output, but now it's no longer unique. It's counter all I's in all sentences. It doesn't matter if I is in the sentence once or more, as soon as it finds first occurence, it should print the index of that sentence out.
And also, I am not used to enumerate, is there any other way of doing this? I will read up on enumerate, but I would prefer if there was a different way of solving this.

The out put I am getting is the following-----:

{'do': [2], 'say': [0, 1], 'i': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2], 'mean': [0, 1], 'what': [0, 1]}

Comment: @Mehul use set Function u get unique values.i will update that or just check now. enumerate is nothing but it returns a tuple (index,value) for every element in list

Comment: I think I will borrow your  idea and method of using counterList like that. But I will need to look at enumerate in more details since it looks like it makes the for loop a little easier.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is going wrong while you are assigning `index`. Currently your word structure in each iteration goes like this
`for`

Eg:

for first iteration

Words=[I,say,what,i,mean]

and when you try to find the index of word it return the index in that sentence and not the sentence number.

Instead you can keep a counter for loop at sentence level and you do not need to find index
just assign that counter value to each word found in a sentence.

```
index=-1
for sentence in myList:
    words = sentence.split()
    index++
    for word in words:
        counterList.append(index)
        if word not in myDict:
            myDict[word] = list()
            myDict[word].append(index)
        else:
            myDict[word]= list()
            myDict[word].append(index)
```